# Alinhar meus botões dentro do JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, css

Importei [Tabledit Jquery](https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/) em  minha página, mas por algum motivo, os icons não estão ficando alinhados como deveriam ser, como eu posso estar implementando css para os `buttons` ficarem alinhados (um do lado do outro)?

[image: PRINT]

**Code:**

```
 $('#example').Tabledit({
 ...
 buttons: {
            edit: {
                html: '<span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span>',
                action: 'edit'
            },
            delete: {
                html: '<span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span>',
                action: 'delete'
            },
            save: {
                class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
                html: 'Save'
            },
            confirm: {
                class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
                html: 'Confirm'
            }
        },
 });
```

Através do meu navegador, aparece dessa forma:

[image: Code navegador]

> Tentei alterar os `float`, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Seu problema então não é com os ícones, e sim com o btn Save.

Comment: Coloca a classe display-inline-block no botão para ver se resolve.

Comment: edite sua pergunta, coloque o output do html da parte da linha do botao... Dificil ajudar sem ter informacoes mais completas...

Comment: @caiovisk editei o post, ve se ajuda em alguma coisa....

Comment: Coloque uma div em torno dos botões, e nela coloque pelo css com flex: `flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; min-width: 180px`, veja se resolveu. Leia um pouco sobre [flexbox aqui](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/css-guia-do-flexbox) e [aqui](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/)

Comment: Como eu faria isso em meu `code` representado acima?

Comment: Vc pode reescrever qualquer elemento, chegou a ver a [documentação](https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#documentation), mas dá pra usar [wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/):  `$('#example').Tabledit({...}).find('[type="button"]').wrap( "<div class='content-buttons'></div>" );`

Comment: Ao inves da imagem, que nao ajuda tanto, voce consegueria colocar o codigo HTML??? de qualquer forma, coloque no seu stylesheet `.tabledit-toolbar { display: flex; }` e veja se funciona

Comment: @caiovisk amigo, eu não tenho esse code html, não está em meus codigos, eu estou importando a `Tabledit`, que consequentemente traz esses codes ao browser.

Comment: Não funcionou @IvanFerrer

Comment: Cola o código inteiro num  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) pra ver o problema real.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dj3fnxkc/9/ , não consegui importar os icons, para ser exibido o botão editar, deletar, confirmar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando voce posta alguma uma forma para reproduzirmos o erro, fica mais facil para a gente lhe ajudar... É um "fix" simples no seu CSS...

Sua div `.btn-toolbar` esta aplicando `flex-wrap: wrap;` o que significa que o flex-wrap esta forcando os elementos que nao cabem na mesma linha para a linha de baixo...

Se voce simplesmente der o override dessa regra, voce soluciona o seu problema:

```
.tabledit-toolbar.btn-toolbar {
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/37qdj6f9/

Comment: obrigado amigo deu certo!

Comment: eu tenho uma outra duvida, não sei se você poderia me ajudar... na documentação, mostra que eu posso utilizar com select também, dessa maneira -->`[2, 'color', '{"1": "Red", "2": "Green", "3": "Blue"}']`, porém preciso que os valores sejam puxados da minha tabela do banco de dados, pesquisei muito, e não encontrei nada relacionado...